# How to prove that $\sqrt[3]{7+5\sqrt{2}} = 1+\sqrt{2} $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to prove that $\sqrt[3]{7+5\sqrt{2}} = 1+\sqrt{2}$ by algebraic manipulation.

I've tried to manipulate the left side by cubing but unable to get to an answer.

The only thing I can find that is similar is https://www.quora.com/Can-anyone-tell-the-solution-of-this-question-7-+-5-sqrt-2-1-3-+-7-5-sqrt-2-1-3 but still can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use $(\cdot)^3$ on both sides of the equation.

Comment: $x\to x^3$ is bijective on $\mathbb{R}$. Since $(1+\sqrt{2})^3 = 7+5\sqrt{2}$, the claim is trivial.

Comment: Finding the cube root of some expression in relatively simple terms is not necessarily easy.  Proving that an expression is the cube root of another expression is a simple matter of cubing the first expression.

Comment: I tried to find if $7+5\sqrt{2}$ can be manipulated to allow it to be cube rooted. I've also tried to multiply it by $\frac{7-5\sqrt{2}}{7-5\sqrt{2}}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  following up on the linked answer, let $a=\sqrt[3]{7+5\sqrt{2}}$ and $b=\sqrt[3]{7-5\sqrt{2}}\,$. Then $a^3+b^3=14$ and $ab=-1\,$, therefore:

$$
(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)=14-3(a+b)
$$

It follows that $a+b$ is a root of $x^3+3x-14=0\,$, but the only real root is $x=2\,$, so $a+b=2$.

Since $a+b=2$ and $ab=-1$, then $a,b$ must be the roots of the quadratic $x^2-2x-1=0$ and, in particular, $a$ must be the positive root.

Answer (score 2):

Cubing both sides gives:
$$7+5\sqrt{2} = (1+\sqrt{2})^3$$
The right hand side is equal to:
$$(1+\sqrt{2})(1+\sqrt{2})^2$$
Which equals:
$$(1+\sqrt{2})^2 + \sqrt{2}(1+\sqrt{2})^2$$
Which equals:
$$(1 + 2\sqrt{2} + 2) + \sqrt{2}(1 + 2\sqrt{2}+2)$$
Which equals:
$$(3 + 2\sqrt{2}) + (\sqrt{2} + 4 + 2\sqrt{2})$$
Which equals:
$$7 + 5\sqrt{2}$$
Which was the left hand side of the first equation I wrote, and therefore proves your equation is true.

Answer (score 1):

A well known simplest method:

Degree of root is $3$, for this reason we can write:

$(1+\sqrt2)^3=1+3\sqrt2+6+2\sqrt2=7+5\sqrt2$

Done.

Comment: So since $(\sqrt{2}-3)^2 = 11-6\sqrt{2}$ we also have $$\sqrt{11-6\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{2}-3 < 0 ? $$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\sqrt[3]{7+5\sqrt{2}} = a +b \sqrt{2}$ with $a,b \in \Bbb{Z}$.  Then

$$
\begin{align}
a^3+3a^2b\sqrt{2}+3ab^22+b^32\sqrt{2}&= 7 + 5 \sqrt{2} \\
(a^3+6ab^2) + (3a^2b+2b^3)\sqrt{2} &= 7 + 5 \sqrt{2} \\
\end{align}
$$

So we're looking for integer solutions to 
$$
\begin{align}
a(a^2+6b^2) &= 7 \\
b(3a^2+2b^2) &= 5
\end{align}
$$

These have the obvious solution $a=1$ and $b=1$

Comment: How does $a=-1$ produce a solution?

Comment: @abiessu  Thanks.  Forgot to test in the first equation.

Comment: How do we know that $(a^3+6ab^2) + (3a^2b+2b^3)\sqrt{2} = 7 + 5 \sqrt{2}$ can be split so that we can say $a(a^2 + 6b^2) = 7$ and $(3a^2 + 2b^2) = 5$ ? Is it because $\sqrt{2}$ is the only term in the second part ? And if so, how can we be certain that the first part cannot be manipulated to contain $\sqrt{2}$ ?

Comment: We're assuming $7+5\sqrt{2}$ is a perfect cube in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$, so that it equals $a+b\sqrt{2}$ for some integers $a$ and $b$.  That's true because $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$ are an integral basis for $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$.  Thus the terms not containing $\sqrt{2}$ must equal 7, and the terms containing $\sqrt{2}$ must equal 5.  Remember $a$ and $b$ are integers.

Comment: Your answer has shed some light on the question :) Although I'm finding it hard to follow, do you know where I can find more on this?

Comment: For a problem solving hands on introduction to Algebraic Number Theory Daniel Marcus *Number Fields* is very good assuming you've completed a bit of Abstract Algebra.